# How to get value of 'body' object from Slim_Http_Request Object

Tags: angularjs, slim

In my angular application i'm using slim framework as server. Stuck to body value from Slim_Http_Request Object ,

My app.js code snippet ,

```
MyApp.controller('Remove', function($scope,$http,$location) {
 $scope.del = function(id) {
    var data = {id:id};
     console.log(id);
     $http.post('api/index.php/del_user',data).success(function(){
  });
   $scope.reset();
 }
});
```

My view ,

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
  <td>{{user.username}}</td>
  <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
  <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
  <td>{{user.address}}</td>
  <td><a class="btn btn-primary" ng-controller="Remove" ng-click="del(user.id)">Del</a>           </td>
</tr>
```

When i print ,

```
$request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($request);die;
```

Got response in XHR ,

```
<pre>Slim_Http_Request Object
(
[method:protected] => POST
[headers:protected] => Array
    (
        [host] => localhost
        [connection] => keep-alive
        [content-length] => 10
        [accept] => application/json, text/plain, */*
        [origin] => http://localhost
        [x-requested-with] => XMLHttpRequest
        [user-agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
        [content-type] => application/json;charset=UTF-8
        [referer] => http://localhost/ag_test/
        [accept-encoding] => gzip,deflate,sdch
        [accept-language] => en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,gu;q=0.2
        [cookie] => request_method=GET; _funkyfish_session=TTZtakRpQnd3WGl5SW9INklFZmd0dUdrV2JlTWdYZmo3YmpPazdKVlBtSzRQSHZYdlR5ZzFza2UzWUY0V2Q0clRQakJZMU1OS0FlTUdlemNzMzlIcFZFWDlmN2dVVGxNcUpLZzNRNHp4TVNpRm4vQVNxcWhwNUdhS0JDczZkOTVsZWZ0NUZZTzZZbllzK1Ntem1pVG1hSi9zeVErVWxUSk9rTlE3WVhzV005SmgzZ2NIQ3RMV0FrZEdtSFBoWHFLaFk4d2FlNnVVNkd6TVRkQU5pMGVEWGYvSi8wWk9TT0ltM2lWSlBpaTc5KzhqNy9oVDczQThZNHVvbUVEZVZVVDltZ0Vqa3R5OGpTdTVIR1VveVRsU1E9PS0tb3N0RGUvZFpNNXNlKzRXaE5tUXJvUT09--e090007458a370fcfe4a51ca4b55aa2dca6417cb; PHPSESSID=5c2a395dee4c4ed55d2885d2d6184527; 5c2a395dee4c4ed55d2885d2d6184527=DEFAULT%7C0%7C2M3TMlgUx3gTlaarYzHIdD28l8q9FTcNubt55%2BUGpAo%3D%7C7456bf61db3500c8bb7b3bc38082a470ce4a2ad3
    )

[additionalHeaders:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => content-type
        [1] => content-length
        [2] => php-auth-user
        [3] => php-auth-pw
        [4] => auth-type
        [5] => x-requested-with
    )

[cookies:protected] => Array
    (
        [request_method] => GET
        [_funkyfish_session] => TTZtakRpQnd3WGl5SW9INklFZmd0dUdrV2JlTWdYZmo3YmpPazdKVlBtSzRQSHZYdlR5ZzFza2UzWUY0V2Q0clRQakJZMU1OS0FlTUdlemNzMzlIcFZFWDlmN2dVVGxNcUpLZzNRNHp4TVNpRm4vQVNxcWhwNUdhS0JDczZkOTVsZWZ0NUZZTzZZbllzK1Ntem1pVG1hSi9zeVErVWxUSk9rTlE3WVhzV005SmgzZ2NIQ3RMV0FrZEdtSFBoWHFLaFk4d2FlNnVVNkd6TVRkQU5pMGVEWGYvSi8wWk9TT0ltM2lWSlBpaTc5KzhqNy9oVDczQThZNHVvbUVEZVZVVDltZ0Vqa3R5OGpTdTVIR1VveVRsU1E9PS0tb3N0RGUvZFpNNXNlKzRXaE5tUXJvUT09--e090007458a370fcfe4a51ca4b55aa2dca6417cb
        [PHPSESSID] => 5c2a395dee4c4ed55d2885d2d6184527
        [5c2a395dee4c4ed55d2885d2d6184527] => DEFAULT|0|2M3TMlgUx3gTlaarYzHIdD28l8q9FTcNubt55+UGpAo=|7456bf61db3500c8bb7b3bc38082a470ce4a2ad3
    )

[get:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[post:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[put:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[body:protected] => {"id":"8"}
[contentType:protected] => application/json
[resource:protected] => /del_user
[root:protected] => /ag_test/api/index.php
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get the JSON object in the body of the request, you should be able to get this in Slim by using

```
$body = Slim::getInstance()->request()->getBody();
$id = $body["id"];
```

Wasn't sure if this was what you were trying to do?